# Custom Layout Android Compose measurable width

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a Custom "Row" Layout in Android compose like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomLayout(modifier: Modifier, content: @Composable () -> Unit){
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
          measurable.measure(constraints)
        }
        var xPos = 0

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                placeable.placeRelative(x = xPos, y = 0)
                xPos += placeable.width
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the preview for this composable:

```kotlin
@Preview(name = "Preview")
@Composable
fun customLayoutPreview() {
    CustomLayout(Modifier.size(1080.dp,100.dp)){
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(32.dp, 64.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)) {

        }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(100.dp, 64.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)) {

        }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(32.dp, 64.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)) {

        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that each `measurable` (Box), after being measured, got parent width, hence, 1080dp, and not the desired width passed to the boxes which caused the first child to take all space.

see:
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7jkj.png)

What is expected to be in theory:
(Box 32dp)(Box 100dp)(Box 32dp)

What I'm missing here?

I tried the documentation, but I could not understand a way to achieve something like plain android Custom `ViewGroup.onMeasure` like :
`view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(wantedSize, AT_MOST or EXACT))`, where `wantedSize` can be fetched from LayoutParams or from the `WRAP_CONTENT` strategy.

Environment:
Android Studio Arctic Fox.
Compose: 1.0.0.
Kotlin: 1.5.10.
AGP and Gradle: 7.0.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make a copy of your constraints and change the min to 0. Change it like this:

```
@Composable
fun CustomLayout(modifier: Modifier, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        // MAKE A COPY WITH 0 FOR MIN
        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            minHeight = 0
        )
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
        }
        var xPos = 0

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                placeable.placeRelative(x = xPos, y = 0)
                xPos += placeable.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this answer saved my life. Even though a better explanation would have been awesome

Comment: Can you provide explanation please?

Comment: The incoming constraints, from the parent, are forcing the child to fill the width (maybe with a fillMaxWidth, or maybe there is a Surface that enforces constraints on their children). Another possible solution would be to wrap the composable in wrapContentWidth.

Answer (score -1):

Ok you should not use `placeable.measuredWidth` over there. Just replace it with `placeable.width`. Also, in your mapping logic, you don't at all need that `val`. Just do this

```
val placeables = measurables.map {
           it.measure(constraints)    
        }
```

Visit here to learn more

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#6

Comment: measured width and width in my case above has the same value, constraints should be copied and have min values set to 0 and then run measure