# Jetpack Compose Measurable.measure() always return width and height of the parent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a custom layout ( Staggered grid layout with flexible row/column sizes ).

I think I have the logic, but the problem is that each time I call the `measure()` method on my `Measurables` objects, instead of considering the arguments I pass in the modifier argument of each children, the method always returns the height and width of the parent.

Here's my Staggred Grid deffinition:

```
@Composable
fun MyStaggeredGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    rows: Int,
    columns: Int,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(content = content, modifier = modifier) { measurables, constaints ->
        ... some code here ...
        val placelables = measurables.mapIndexed { index, measurable ->
            val placelable = measurable.measure(constaints)

            val childrenWidth = placelable.width
            val childrenHeight = placelable.height 
        ... some code here ...
  }
```

here's how I add children to `MyStaggeredGrid`

```
MyStaggeredGrid(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(400.dp)
            .width(200.dp),
        rows = 4,
        columns = 2
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.5f),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.myimg),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.25f),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.myimg),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.5f),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.myimg),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.25f),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.myimg),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
```

so, for the first image I add, I have set `.fillMaxWidth(1f)` and `.fillMaxHeight(0.5f)`, meaning that when I call the `measure()` method of it, it should return *width 200dp* and *height 200dp* (in pixels of course).

However the method returns *width 200dp* and *height 400dp* .

for 4 children is the same.

Any idea, how can I make the measure() method to take into account my constraints ?

Comment: I've found the answer to my question .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605479/custom-layout-android-compose-measurable-width